# UV masking with an LCD

Tags: pcb-design, lcd, pcb-fabrication, uv

I am planning to make a machine that uses an LCD screen as a mask for etching PCBs. However, I am concerned about the type of LCD that I would need as well as the accuracy that I would get.

My main concern is that regular LCDs (like from a mobile device or laptop) have a UV light masking feature that would absolutely derail my project. Do they only block a certain frequency? What would I need to do to make a regular LCD screen work?

Additionally, I know that there is some light distortion going on within the liquid crystals in LCDs. How could I increase my accuracy?

If anybody has any information or knows anything about this please respond. Anything would help.

Comment: Some resin 3D printers use an LCD and UV light.

Comment: yes, I know, but buying the ones specifically for them are expensive, so I'm asking if anything from a common household device would work. Thank you though